# Joomla not responsive

Tags: responsive-design, joomla3.0

I recently migrated a website to Joomla, the old website used bootstrap and was responsive.
However, when I used the same template on the new website powered by Joomla it isn't responsive at all.

I thought it would be responsive by nature, is there any additional configuration to make to get it responsive ?

Note: I am not a web designer, so simple explanations would be great.

Comment: Can you share the site URL? On the one hand you mention that you migrated the site to Joomla which implies that the old site wasn't on Joomla. On the other hand you mention that you used the same template which implies the old site was Joomla ... it will be easier to figure out if we see the live site.

Answer (score 0):

Basically Joomla works out of the box with some old style templates. Although bootstrap is already into the joomla libraries it doesn't mean that it is used.

Fortunately there are many free templates with their own framework that use bootstrap to have a ready to use responsive website.

I feel to suggest the helix framework http://www.joomshaper.com/helix , it is also very easy to use and customise.

Or the new gantry5 http://gantry.org/ but it doesn't use bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use Gantry 5 framework. It is free, light and easy to use if you are not a developer.
It does support Bootstrap but they are using there own responsive framework.

http://gantry.org